# PHP: unable to move file to different folder

Tags: php, apache, centos7, php-7.1, fpm

I'm trying to move a file uploaded with PHP to a different folder, but somehow this will not work, resulting in:

`move_uploaded_file(upload/tmp/phpxEGMLG): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

So, apparently I do not have proper permissions for `upload/tmp` (which is in fact `/var/www/html/upload/tmp`).

I've set permissions to `777` and owner `root:root` for `/var/www/html/upload/tmp` to be absolutely sure there couldn't be a problem.
But that didn't solve it...

Other things I've tried:

- Set owner to `apache:apache`
- Change source file permissions to `777` and owner `root` (by default, owner is set to `apache`)
- Checking PHP settings (pretty much default, `/var/www/html` and `/tmp` are inside `open_basedir`, `upload_tmp_dir` is not set) + logs
- Checking Apache settings + logs
- Moving the file within the same folder --> this works!
- Moving it to a different other folder  --> doesn't work
- Setting all parent directories to `777` and owner `root` or `apache`

And I created a test script:

```
<?php

echo 'TESTING FILE MOVE' . '<br><br>';

echo getcwd() . '<br>';
echo get_current_user() . '<br>';

error_reporting(E_ALL);

file_put_contents('/tmp/tst.txt', 'this is a test');
chdir('/var/www/html/upload/tmp');
echo getcwd() . '<br><br>';
rename('/tmp/tst.txt', 'tst-2.txt');

print_r(error_get_last());
```

It gives an output like:

> TESTING FILE MOVE
>
> /var/www/html
>   root
>   /var/www/html/upload/tmp
>
> Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => rename(/tmp/tst.txt,tst-2.txt):
>   Permission denied [file] => /var/www/html/test.php [line] => 13 )

This tells me under which user the script is running and I'm in the right directory. It also omits the extra checks `move_uploaded_file` uses, focussing on the moving of the file.

Some info about my setup:

- CentOS 7
- PHP 7.1
- PHP-FPM
- Apache 2.4.6

It uses a separate temp directory for PHP-FPM, like `/tmp/systemd-private-xxxx-php71-php-fpm.service-yyyy/tmp/`. Perhaps there is some reason it cannot move files outside this directory? I can't find anything on that though...

I hope someone can provide me with a clue as to what might be going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be **SELinux**.

More or less the same question answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50639/httpd-cant-write-to-folder-file-because-of-selinux

I did have the webserver folders setup with SELinux to be available to Apache, while also allowing FTP read/write. But I needed to set the `upload` folder (and folders underneath it) to allow read/write by Apache, which can be accomplished by something like this (note the `rw` bit in the command):

```
chcon --user system_u --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t -R upload
```

Also, a handy command for checking:

```
ls -Z
```

This now shows:

```
drwxr-xr-x. apache  apache  system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 upload
```

Answer (score 0):

change owner of the directory or the webser to `www-data` and add yourself to `www-data` group, logout or restart.

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www
```

[chown help](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) and [chmod help](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

Comment: `www-data` doesn't exist on CentOS, it's called `apache` there, but executing these commands with `apache` instead of `www-data` doesn't solve it...

Answer (score 0):

Set PrivateTmp to false under [Service] (probably you have to create an unit file named httpd.service in /etc/systemd/system). Please let us know